# How do you set the volume of an embedded youtube video from HTML and/or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, html5-video

[image: Current code]

I'm currently creating a "start page" of sorts for myself, and want to put music in the background. I've chosen a youtube livestream that I quite like, and cannot figure out how to change the volume using code, because I do not want it to be at the maximum volume constantly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide the actual code not the screenshot...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Playback_controls), you can use the function:

```
player.setVolume(volume:Number):Void
```

That will set the volume between 0 and 100.

---

PS: you should do the [getting started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Getting_Started) part to get the reference to the `player` variable.